# Dotcloud CLI Deploy not found

Tags: python, django, command-line-interface, dotcloud

Could anyone let me know the current version of the Dotcloud CLI? I'm working with 0.4.7 on my  machine and can't seem to find a new version in pip/easy_install or online.

However, in the tutorial for deploying django, It says to run the dotcloud deploy command, and I don't seem to have that in my version?

Comment: `0.4.7` seems to be the latest version: http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/dotcloud.cli/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking at the current version of the Python/Django tutorial?
http://docs.dotcloud.com/tutorials/python/django/

CLI version 0.4.7 is the latest official version, and in that version you should use `dotcloud push`

/A

Comment: Thanks it seems that I was using an outdate django tutorial.